# Find analytical function in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

Which are the functions $f$ that are analytical in $\mathbb{C}$ and for which it holds that $f(x)^2=e^{2x}$ for each $x$ in the line segment $[0,1]$ ?

My idea is to use that $e^{2x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k 2^k}{k!}$.

So, we are looking for functions $f$ so that it holds $f(x)=\pm \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k 2^k}{k!}}$.

How can we get more information?

We have that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=\pm \sqrt{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^k}{k!}}=\pm \sqrt{e^2}=\pm e$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $f^2(x)=(e^x)^2$ for each $x\in[0,1]$. Therefore, by the identity theorem, you have$$(\forall z\in\Bbb C):f^2(z)=(e^z)^2.$$That is$$(\forall z\in\Bbb C):\frac{f(z)}{e^z}=\pm1.$$But $\frac{f(z)}{e^z}$ is continuous and $\Bbb C$ is connected. Therefore, either you always have $\frac{f(z)}{e^z}=1$ or you always have $\frac{f(z)}{e^z}=-1$. In other words, $f=\pm\exp$.